# VBA / sheetname contains "Check_**" ("Check_BC", "Check_BD", "Check_BB"...)

Tags: excel, vba

I am the beginner of VBA. So there are several sheets called "Check_BC", "Check_BD", "Check_BB"... among the other sheets.

If there is TRUE value in those sheets, Range("C5:DD90"), write "PASS" in "Summary" sheet. Otherwise there is at least one FALSE value, write "FAIL".

I got stuck in choosing sheets which have named "Check_**"

The error line is  checksh = Worksheets("sh") and the error is "Subscript out of range"
Hope I'm not doing stupid. Thanks.

```
Sub findtrial()

 Dim c As Range
 Dim checkrange As Range
 Dim ws_1 As Worksheet
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim checksh As Worksheet
 
 i = Sheets.Count
 sh = Sheets(i).Name = "Check_**"
 checksh = Worksheets("sh")
 
 Set ws_1 = Worksheets("Summary")
 
 Do While i > 0
 
 If Sheets(i).Name = "Check_**" Then
 
 Set checkrange = checksh.Range("C5:DD90")

  With checkrange

     Set c = .Find(False, Lookat:=xlWhole)
         If Not c Is Nothing Then
            ws_1.Range("C2").Select
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
            Selection.Value = "FAIL"
         Else
            ws_1.Range("C2").Select
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = "43"
            Selection.Value = "PASS"
            
         End If
            
   End With
  
 End If
 i = i - 1
 Loop
 
End Sub
```

[image: when the false value comes out]
when the false value comes out

[image: FAIL should be in the Summary tab]
FAIL should be in the Summary tab

[image: all the tabs in workbook]
all the tabs in workbook

Comment: I still get the error in line ' checksh = Worksheets("sh")' with the error sign "Subscript out of range"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check If No Occurrence of `False` in Multiple Worksheets

[image]

```
Not Checking "Summary"...
Checking "Check_df"...
Checking "check_DD"...
```

[image]

**The Code**

```vb
Sub CheckFailPass()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, HasFailed As Boolean
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If LCase(ws.Name) Like "check_??" Then ' it's a match; check it
            Debug.Print "Checking """ & ws.Name & """..."
            With ws.Range("C5:DD98")
                If Not .Find(False, , xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                    HasFailed = True
                    Exit For ' one fail is enough: stop checking
                End If
            End With
        Else ' it's not a match; do nothing (don't check this worksheet)
            Debug.Print "Not Checking """ & ws.Name & """..."
        End If
    Next ws
   
    With wb.Sheets("Summary").Range("C2")
        If HasFailed Then
            .Value = "FAIL"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
        Else
            .Value = "PASS"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = "43"
        End If
    End With
 
End Sub
```

**Some Thoughts**

- There are many details in your code so it's hard to believe that you would run it on multiple workbooks. Therefore specify the workbook explicitly:

  - For the workbook containing this code use (should be most often):

    ```
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ```
  - For another workbook, specify it like this (also specify the file extension):

    ```
    Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsx")
    ```
  - If the workbook is closed, to open it (best specify the complete path), use:

    ```
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Test.xlsx")
    ```
  - If you plan on running the code from an add-in or from `PERSONAL.xlsb` using it on a workbook that is active at the moment, use:

    ```
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ```
- The `Sheets` collection consists of all the worksheets and charts in the workbook. In your code, you are reading from worksheets so use the `Worksheets` collection. Since you are not interested in the number of worksheets (you need to check each if it is named after the string pattern), it is far more readable to use a `For Each...Next` loop.

  ```
  For Each ws in wb.Worksheets ' not 'wb.Sheets'!
  Next ws
  ```
- In your particular case, you can use the `Like` operator to compare the worksheet names with the string pattern. Note that the comparison is case-sensitive (`A<>a`) so you can use the `LCase` function to return the worksheet name in lowercase and compare it with the lowercase pattern to make the comparison case-insensitive. The pattern "check_??" means that the string starts with "check_" and ends with two additional characters.

  ```
  If LCase(ws.Name) Like "check_??" Then
  ```
- Using `Debug.Print` is a very useful way to monitor what is going on in the code.

  ```
  Debug.Print "Checking """ & ws.Name & """..."
  Debug.Print "Not Checking """ & ws.Name & """..."
  ```
- By using the `LookIn` argument's `xlValues` parameter, you are ensuring the `Find` method will find `False` as the result of a formula. Note that the `Find` method with `xlValues` will fail if rows or columns are hidden and if the worksheet is filtered.

  ```
  .Find(False, , xlValues, xlWhole)
  ```
- Once you have hit a match, you can use a `Boolean` flag and exit the loop.

  ```
  HasFailed = True
  Exit For
  ```
- Using the flag (`True` or `False`), you will construct the final `If` statement.

  ```
  If HasFailed Then
  Else
  End If
  ```
- Selecting and activating slows down the code so it is to be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But there is a problem when I ran your code... if I change one value as a "FALSE", it still shows "PASS" in the summary tab... I added some screenshots for more details. Thanks!

Comment: In case you haven't figured it out: `False` in the *Find* method is a boolean yet now (or in the first place) you have decided to search for a string; so simply put the `False` in double quotes `... .Find("False", ...`.